# Why does my mysqli_query return false?

Tags: php, mysql

I realise there are a lot of questions like this here, but none of them seem to help me. The problem is as follows:

I have a website with an SQL Database, and now I am developing an application that reads the data. I've read that the best way to do that is a web service, so I'm in the process of writing one now. First, I'm trying to get all the data to display on a webpage, for testing purposes. I have the following code now:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "myusername";
$password = "mypassword";
$db = "mydatabase";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db, 3306);

// Check connection
if (!$conn){echo "Not connected";} else {echo "connected";}

$query = "SHOW TABLES FROM mydata";
$result = mysqli_query($query) or die(" but not executed" . mysqli_error());
?>
```

When I save this and go to mywebsite/test.php, it displays the following:

connected but not executed. That means that it connects right, but the mysqli_query() returns false. However, mysqli_error is empty.

This is the entire test.php file. Am I missing something?

Comment: you are connected to database 'mydatabase' and trying to get tables from 'mydata' database. Just use "SHOW TABLES". And use $conn->query("SHOW TABLES") instead of mysqli_query

Comment: `mysqli_error` requires connection as an argument.

Comment: No errors reported? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`
Add error checking, such as `or die(mysqli_error($conn))` to your queries. Or you can find the issues in your current error logs.

Comment: `$conn->query($query);` dont mix oop with procedual....   and this is right: `mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query)` you missing the first arg

Comment: @Nitin that is bad information. The MySQLi API is just as safe as PDO if used with prepared statements.

Comment: Did not know you can use prepared statements with mysqli. Sorry for that.

Comment: as does `mysqli_query()` which requires db argument

Answer (score 0):

> *"Am I missing something?"*

Yes, db connection arguments to both `mysqli_query()` and `mysqli_error()`.

RTM's

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

It's all in there.

- Btw, this is a community wiki. No rep should come of this.

If that still doesn't work, then you may have to remove the port `, 3306`.

Answer (score 0):

Your $query appears to say

> SHOW TABLES FROM mydata

However, your database is actually called mydatabase, as demonstrated on the $db line.